# LLPSI: Cap. XIII, '...quibus haec sunt nōmina...'

Tags: syntax, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, demonstrative-pronoun

My question concerns the sentence which begins at Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata, chapter 13, line 1.

What are the cases of 'haec' and 'nōmina' in the following excerpt?

> "Annus in duodecim mēnses̄ dīuiditur, quibus haec sunt nōmina: Iānuārius, mēnsis prīmus; Februārius, secundus; Mārtius, tertius; Aprīlis, quārtus; Māius, quīntus; Iūnius, sextus; Iūlius, septimus; Augustus, octāuus; September, nōnus; Octōber, decimus; Nouember, ūndecimus; December, mēnsis duodecimus ac postrēmus."

[image]

I think that 'quibus haec sunt nōmina' directs the readers attention to the names of the months in an 'Annus'. However, I cannot determine whether 'nōmina' is nominative or accusative based on the form of 'haec'.

### Theory

'Quibus' is representative of the dative of possession, and 'haec' directs attention to the subject that 'sunt' affects, which may then mean 'nōmina' is nominative plural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nominative and for a less complicated reason than the one you posited. For one, it can't be accusative, because *haec* and *nomina* are all that exists in the relative clause, for which the relative pronoun is dative.

Since there is no preposition which could make them accusative and no transitive verb that takes a direct object, it has to be nominative. At any rate, you would need a subject, and the subject of a linking verb in direct speech is nominative.

So to translate, it should read: "for which these (*haec*) are (*sunt*) the names (*nomina*).